# explanation of odoo filter domain operator "child_of" and its preference over "in" operator

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am uncertain regarding what `child_of` does after reading the docs and the use of `child_of` operator over using `in` operator for filtering

Odoo v10 domain docs can be found [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#domains) which states the following for `child_of`

```
is a child (descendant) of a value record.
Takes the semantics of the model into account (i.e following the relationship field named by _parent_name)
```

Consider the model `product.product` having a many2one field called `pos_categ_id` that points to model `pos.category`

To only get products with PoS category id of `x`, domain value of `['pos_categ_id', 'child_of', x]` can be used, however `['pos_categ_id', 'in', [x]]` seems to also do the same thing.

In addition to that, `in` operator can be used for many2many and one2many fields with same format as above example while use of `child_of` operator for those two field types cause errors.

Example the domain `['session_ids', 'child_of', [572]]` where `session_ids` is a many2many field causes the following error `Invalid field 'parent_id' in leaf \"<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('parent_id', 'in', [572]) on pos_session (ctx: )>\"`

So, what is the example case where `child_of` is preferred over `in` operator? Both seems to function the same except `in` can work on all types of relational fields. Second, what does the second line of docs for `child_of` mean by the phrase `following the relationship field named by _parent_name`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No they are not the same**, yes they are the same in the simple example that you used:

> To only get products with PoS category id of x, domain value of
>   ['pos_categ_id', 'child_of', x]  can be used, however ['pos_categ_id',
>   'in', [x]] seems to also do the same thing.

But consider this case:

```
#               x                
#              / \               
#             f   b                
#                / \               
#               c   d
```

when we do this  `['pos_categ_id', 'child_of', x]` this will return product that their category is one of this list `[x, f, b, c, d]` it's equivalent to  `['pos_categ_id', 'in', [x, f, b, c, d]]`.
because they are all child of x **(`child_of` includes x itself)**.

but this:  `['pos_categ_id', 'in', [x]]`  will return only product that their category is `X` but will not return  product with category `b or c ..etc`.

To activate this feature in your custom model you should set this attribute

```py
  class YourModel(models.Model):
     _name = 'some.model'
     _parent_name = 'parent_id'  # by default its name is parent_id you can change it
     _parent_store = True  # tell odoo that this model support parent & child relation ship

     # same name of _parent_name 
     parent_id = fields.Many2one('some.model', 'Parent')
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `child_of` functionality is provided by odoo, not python.

But to understand it you must need to knowledge of `parent`, 'child` relationship in database concept.

If any of your tables are using a **self join** like below example.

`_name = 'my.table'`

**`parent_id = fields.Many2one('my.table', string='Parent Id')`**

In the above case, your model has connected itself. In this type of cases in Odoo, you can use `child_of` operator in the domain.

So, it will search in database like `parent_id = <your_value>`.

**For `in` domain,**

You can pass the list of data which you need to search in `id` field. It similar to any database `in` operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _parent_name = 'parent_partner_id'  # the many2one field used as parent 
    _parent_store = True

    parent_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', store=True)        
    parent_path = fields.Char(index=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.